# How do I use php-cgi?

Tags: php, cgi

So, right now my custom webserver uses file IO to pass the PHP file to PHP-CGI.exe, and then read and return the output to the user. How do I use stdin to input to PHP-CGI to cut out the hard drive in the cycle? I know FCGI is better, but one step at a time. :)

I can't find any good and relevant documentation on how to do this. Basic Question: stdin for php-cgi?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249427/how-to-process-stdin-to-stdout-in-php)?

Comment: @Keo nope, I'm talking webserver->cgi communication